# More general usage of the term 'congener'

Tags: terminology, taxonomy

In taxonomy the term 'congener' refers to two species within the same genus. In more colloquial usage, it can refer to any two objects within the same category. Is there a way to refer to related species that is not specific to a particular taxonomic rank--as in, in the same order or family but not necessarily the same genus?

Update: I guess the term 'relative' works, but I still wonder if there's a better term.

Comment: _Confamiliar_ is used sometimes (just google it). At lower taxonomic levels, such a term somehow loses its meaning, doesn't it?

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence where you'd like to use this term? I'm finding it hard to understand why you wouldn't just use the family or order name itself (i.e., "Tigers, like other big cats, ..." instead of "tigers, like their confamiliars, ...")